# Inflate Exception while using here maps SDK

Tags: android, here-api

I am using here maps but I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lifesessentia.tat_manager/com.lifesessentia.tat.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2373)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:374)
  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:33)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:75)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
```

I have followed SDK user guide. I am able to use SDK for other app with different app id but not with this one.

This is my activity_map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
  >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/the_List"
/>




<!-- Map Fragment embedded with the map object -->
<fragment
    class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


  </LinearLayout>
```

In logcat it can be seen that error is caused due to null pointer exception at fragment class. How I should solve this error?

Sometimes I get these warnings in gradle messages:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.c) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced   by a
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date  compiler
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.l) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.o) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.b) that doesn't come with an
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.r) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.h) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.a.c) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.j) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(com.here.sdk.analytics.internal.k) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
```

This my manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  - <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       
  package="com.lifesessentia.tat">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 

  <application 
   android:allowBackup="true" 
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"     
   android:label="@string/app_name" 
   android:supportsRtl="true" 
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
   android:largeHeap="true" 
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

   <activity android:name=".MapActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" /> 

   <activity android:name=".Login_Activity"  
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity android:name=".Plan_finished_activity"   
   android:screenOrientation="portrait" /> 

  <service android:name=".Database_service" /> 
  <service android:name=".Download_and_Store_Service" /> 
  <service android:name=".Location_alert_service" /> 

  <service 
   android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService"   
   android:label="HereMapService" 
   android:process="global.Here.Map.Service.v2" 
   android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.here.android.mpa.service.MapService" /> 
   </intent-filter>
   </service>

    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid"   
     android:value="----" /> 

    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken"   
     android:value="----" /> 

    <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" 
     android:value="----" /> 
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Which JDK are you using ? Are you compiling via gradle with android studio, command line or ?

Comment: Java JDK version 1.8. Yes I am compiling using gradle with android studio. But same version of SDK worked for other app with different appID and token. And infact, I copied 70% code from that "working app" in this new app.

Comment: Perhaps the permission string is incorrect? Please make sure the appid, appcode, permission string and application package name matches what you entered into our developer portal.

Comment: @DavidLeong Hi David. The appID,appcode(appToken),permission string is correct. And application package name matches the entered into developer portal. I would have added my manifest but how can I leak my appID,appcode,and license key here?

Comment: @DavidLeong I have even checked in settings on device under test, and ideally the here map service should run indefinitely though app is destroyed but its not running in background. is this has to do something with my app crash?

Comment: Can you please post your Android Manifest (just change the appid, key, permission to ------?

Comment: @DavidLeong I have added manifest please review it.

Comment: @DavidLeong I think my AppID,etc is not activated by HERE because the same version of SDK (with different appID etc) works for other app.

Comment: The manifest looks correct. AppID and AppCodes are used mostly in our online services so it does not explain the problem you are experiencing.

Can you please try to re-register the application with namespace "com.lifesessentia.tat" ?

Comment: @DavidLeong Ok I will try it again. And on my same developer account I have two apps with different package names (with different appID and Appcodes!) registered. So is this a problem that one account cannot have two apps? Because one app iw working and other not.

Comment: @DavidLeong I have tried re-registering but the problem was unsolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in `onCreate()` I was calling initialize function before `super.onCreate()` and I solved by calling the super method first and then initialization method. I never thought issue was due to this silly mistake, it took 1 week to find this!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think the problem is really simple:

Please change the code from:

```
<fragment
    class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

To:

```
<com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I will try it report the result.

Comment: Hi I have tried this but the problem didn't solved.But error log is changed. Now Null pointer exception takes place at `mapFragment.init()` in initialize function in map activity.